# What is wrong with this proof of: $2+2 = 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

I have seen this image and surprised that we can prove $2 + 2 = 5$. can any one tell me what is wrong with this image.

> Prove that, $2+2=5$.
>
> We know that, $2+2=4$
>
> $$\begin{align}\Rightarrow2+2&=4-\dfrac92+\dfrac92\\\,\\
> &=\sqrt{\left(4-\dfrac92\right)^2}+\dfrac92\\
> &=\sqrt{16-2\cdot4\cdot\dfrac92+\left(\dfrac92\right)^2}+\dfrac92\\
> &=\sqrt{-20+\left(\dfrac92\right)^2}+\dfrac92\\
> &=\sqrt{(5)^2-2\cdot5\cdot\dfrac92+\left(\dfrac92\right)^2}+\dfrac92\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
> &=\sqrt{\left(5-\dfrac92\right)^2}+\dfrac92\\
> &=5-\dfrac92+\dfrac92\\
> &=5\\\,\\&\therefore\,2+2=5\text{ (Proved)}\\
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Except for $x = 0$, you can't have $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ at the same time. (In other news, if you have $4 - \frac{9}{2} = \sqrt{\left(4-\frac92\right)^2}$, you're working with the negative-valued branch of the square root, then $\sqrt{\left(5-\frac92\right)^2} = - \left(5-\frac92\right)$.)

Comment: $\sqrt{a}$ is only definied if $a\geq 0$

Comment: $\sqrt{\left(4-\frac{9}{2}\right)^{2}} = \frac{9}{2} - 4$

Comment: I see this kind of "math" as being akin to wordplay.

Comment: Indeed, a lot of “proofs” of this nature work by assuming that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ even if $x<0$. Once you have seen half a dozen of them, it gets boring really fast.

Comment: @JosuéMolina, what do u mean.

Comment: »It would be a real blow to math, to say the least, if it could. If it could be proved that two plus two is five, then it could be proved that five is not five, and then there would be no claim that could not be proved, and math would be a lot of bunk.«  (George Boolos, _Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem Explained in Words of One Syllable_.)

Comment: As somebody once upon a time remarked: $\;2+2=5\;$ is true for very high values of $\;2\;$ ...

Comment: Funny thing is, this is not true in every finite field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: Given any real number $x,$ we have $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

Comment: Please make this a complete answer. Means I need details

Comment: In particular, check the step where the square root first appears. Is $4-\frac92=\left|4-\frac92\right|$?

Answer (score 3):

Using this, not only you can prove $4=5$ but you can also prove $a=b$ for all different $a,b$. **BUT** all these fallacies come from a slip in part of the proof. Here the mistake comes from accepting that $\sqrt x$ can be negative. This is just wrong.

Every time you see such a thing, look at steps of proof and definition of operators carefully.

Answer (score 2):

No,its not possible

your second step is wrong

$4-4.5$ is negative number

So $\sqrt{(4-4.5)^2}$ is not possible